# Submit button with text on a wordpress page that writes URL with typed text

Tags: html, forms

I'm trying to create some sort of a simple form where the user writes a text in a box field and this text gets added in the end of an URL.

I've been trying using the GET method but it ads some perameters like "?id=" before the text.
This is the code I've been using:

```
<form name="form" action="https://test.com/aventuras/iniciante/" target="_blank" method="get">
<input type="text" name="id">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

If I type "xxxxx" this code gets me to https://test.com/aventuras/iniciante/?id=xxxxx

But what I want is this URL: https://test.com/aventuras/iniciante/xxxxx

So, how can I remove this parameter: ?id= from the link result?

If this is not possible using forms, is there any other method to do this?

Comment: That's how the form action is designed to work.  Have you check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't see how this would help me, but I'm not an expert with coding.

Comment: `preventDefault` is a way to override default form behavior.  Read the docs about `form` too.  You might want to learn the rules before breaking them.    https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form